# Why does while (str[i] == str[++i]); make an infinite loop?

Tags: c, loops, unary-operator

I want to let `i` be the index of the first character different from `str[i]` (where `str` is an array of `char`).

(Let me ignore the out-of-bound condition here.)

What I tried is:

```
char str[6] = {'h', 'h', 'h', 'a', 'a', '\0'};
int i = 0;
while (str[i] == str[++i]) ;
```

but this falls into an infinite loop. (`i` adds up to some big numbers.)

Same happened with `while (str[i++] == str[i]) ;`.

I know I can successfully do this by:

```
while (str[i] == str[i+1]) i++;
i++;
```

but I don't understand why the first two codes I tried don't work.

Why does `while (str[i] == str[++i]);` lead to an infinite loop?

Comment: This causes undefined behavior, because there's no sequence point between the two sides of the `==`.

Comment: And you get an infinite loop if it's compiled as `while (++i, str[i] == str[i])`

Comment: You're basically assuming that expressions are evaluated left-to-right. That's true in some languages that adopted C syntax (e.g. JavaScript and PHP), but not C itself.

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure (str[i++] == str[i]) does the following:

1. evaluating str[i] == str[i]
2. i++
   to be sure consider using a debugger to step through the code

and the other one just does it in the opposite order

Comment: The OP's code uses pre-increment, not post-increment.

Comment: @Barmar OP tried both.

Comment: *the other one just does it in the opposite order*  There is no "order" to the operations as there is no sequence point in the code.  Reading and modifying the same variable without an intervening sequence point invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: The language doesn't say exactly when the updated value of `i` is stored back, just that it happens *sometimes* before the `;`. Reading it again before it is updated is an error.

Comment: @Eric - Yes, but I was talking about the example `while (str[i++] == str[i]) ;`